# Lazarus Pascal: How to debug a Widget Set (multiline Caption/Hint issue)

Tags: pascal, lazarus, macos-carbon, caption, hint

I'm not the most advanced programmer, but do love working with Lazarus.

Unfortunately, every now and then there is an issue or bug (like [this one](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,28066.0.html), [bugreport](http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=27867)), and I for one would like to help out and see if I can contribute by trying to debug this myself and provide a possible "fix".

The question I have is: How do I debug a widget set or the Object Inspector?

Short reason why:
When I enter a multiline caption or hint under Windows or Linux, then this works fine. Under MacOS X however (Carbon), the newline character(s) gets removed by the Object Inspector or the widget set and I have no clue where to look to try to fix this.

With what I was able to figure out myself; 
I've narrowed down the issue to the Object Inspector or the Carbon widget set. Manually editing a form (lfm) works, doing it at runtime in code works, and multi-line captiosn or hints works fine under Windows and Linux.
So I suspect that the Carbon widget-set, used by the Object Inspector, is doing something wrong.

Any help to get me started is very much appreciated.

I apologize if this question is not appropriate or not specific enough - I'm just trying to find help in debugging this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE Object inspector is actually an advanced version of TTIPropertyGrid.
If you want to debug it you can work on the package and test it in a simple project:

[image]

Then add a simple handler to test the inspector on the project form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TIPropertyGrid1.TIObject := self;
end;
```

When you'll modify a source in the package *RunTimeTypeInfoControls*, the changes won't be visible in the IDE but rather at run-time, in your sample project (package will be automatically recompiled).

It's also probable that you'll have to work on the *PropEdits* unit if the bug comes from the property editor itself (maybe *TStringsPropertyEditor*).

To avoid any laborious manipulation you can test your changes on a copy of the matching editor class and register it in the initialization section of your test project to replace the default, maybe *buged*, version.

Comment: Awesome - this made debugging significantly easier! Thanks Abstract Type! Unfortunately, I did not manage to find the reason why the newline character is being removed, but I did narrow it down to a call to "RefreshValueEdit" (in: lazarus/components/ideintf/ObjectInspector.pp). Unfortunately, nothing "strange" is going on there that I can see or debug.

Comment: Since your answer has been _extremely_ helpful, I'll mark it as the answer to my question ... In the Lazarus Forum a thread can be found related to this topic (http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,32335.0.html).